# torque qsub making jobs dependent on other jobs

Tags: qsub, torque

I'd like to start a bunch of jobs using qsub, and the final job should only run if all the others finished "without error".  In my case "without error" means they exited with status=0.   The man page for qsub says in the -W depend=afterok description that: This job may be scheduled for execution only after jobs jobid have terminated with no errors.

Unfortunately it does not seem to explain (or I can't find) what it means by "with no errors".  It is likely that some of my scripts will print information to stderr, but I don't want that to be interpreted as an error.

Question 1: What does the qsub documentation mean by "with no errors"?
Question 2: How can I make a job dependent explicitly on all of a collection of jobs exiting with status 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With no errors = exited with a status of 0. If the jobs exit with a non-zero exit status, it is considered an error.
2. You can chain dependencies: `qsub -W depend=afterok:job1:job2:job3`

Comment: I ran a test and it does indeed seem that if a job prints to stderr, but exists with status=0, then the error gets printed into the error long, but -W depend=afterok still considers it OK, not failed.   Great.